# Can not import ArrayAdapter library automatically

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, lib

Android  studio version 3.3.1
when I create the ArrayList and than make the ArrayAdapter. Android studio cannot import the ArrayAdapter library automatically. And cannot shows a suggestion of the ArrayAdapter.

Comment: add your code. show us what have you done till now?

Comment: ArrayList can show in the suggestion but the ArrayAdapter word cannot show in suggestion and if manually write the arrayAdapter than android studio cannot import its library automatically.